# best practise for an if/else statement javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the scenario where the else statement is blank, is it's inclusion necessary?
IE:

```
if (condition) {
function
}
else {}
```

or

```
if (condition) {
function
}
```

Comment: No, you don't *need* an `else` statement

Comment: Empty `else` block is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? This takes less than 10 secs.

Comment: You can even write it as `if (condition) function` if you so wanted. Curly braces are your friends tho.

Comment: Only for the short-hand `?` you need a pendant of else (`:`).

Comment: You could have found the answer on google in less time than you took to write this question.

Comment: @PeterRader: and not a full shorthand at that, e.g. you can't throw an error directly from one (it's a statement, not a expression).

Comment: @Numbers: It seems that you haven't flagged a post before. Note that if it's a possible duplicate you can flag it for the attention of high-rep users and moderators by clicking the flag button and selecting the appropriate post.

Comment: Hello World, you asked 15 questions and accepted zero answer? Why ?

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of the `else` statement is not necessary.

```
if (condition) {
    function();
}
```

is enough.

Comment: For single lines in the `if` body, you can even avoid the curly brackets.

Comment: You *can*, but you probably *shouldn't*.